# AWS-API gateway -- jsonschema child object should validate when parent object exists

Tags: aws-api-gateway, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I need to create Jsonschema for the following JSON input. Here properties under Vehicle like( Manufacturer, Model, etc) should be required only when Vehicle object exists.

```
 {
     "Manufacturer": "",
     "Characteristics": {
         "Starts": "new",
         "vehicle": {
             "Manufacturer": "hello",
             "Model": "hh",
             "Opening": "",
             "Quantity": "",
             "Principle": "",
             "Type": ""
         }
     }
 }
```

I tried the following JsonSchema but this works when Vehicle object is not there but if we rename Vehicle to some other ex: Vehicle1 it doesn't give an error. Please guide me on how to fix this.

```
 {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Manufacturer": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "Characteristics": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Starts": {
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "Vehicle": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Vehicle"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "Starts", "Vehcle"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "Manufacturer"
    ],
    

    "definitions": {
        "Vehicle": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Manufacturer": {
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "Model": {
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },

                "Opening": {
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "PanelQuantity": {
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },

                "Principle": {
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                "Type": {
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": ["Manufacturer", "Model", "Opening", "Quantity", "Principle", "Type"]
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to add `"additionalProperties": false` -- which will generate an error if any other properties are present that aren't defined under `properties`.

Comment: I am not sure how this can be done with additionalProperties but my requirement is when  "Characteristics" key exists then all the json properties under "Characteristics" is required.If the "Characteristics" doesnt exists it shouldnt give an error

Comment: thanks Ether.I am able to achieve requirement with additionalProperties